# How to add a FragmentActivity to the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a sliding menu function which calls a number of fragments and replaces each of the fragments with each select of the items from the sliding menu:

```
private void displayView(int position) throws IOException 
{
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) 
    {
    case 0:
        //fragment = new DayListActivity();
        break;
    case 1:
        //fragment = new ItemListActivity();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity_Sliding.this, DayListActivity.class);
        MainActivity_Sliding.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity_Sliding.this, ItemListActivity.class);
        MainActivity_Sliding.this.startActivity(myintent);
        break;
    case 3:
        //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        //fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        //fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container_sliding, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity_Sliding", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Now I have a fragmentactivity which is a list/details view and contains it's own fragments (as it should being a fragmentactivity). What I would like to do is have each of the fragments from the displayView method above load a fragmentactivity. If I change `Fragment fragment = null;` to a `FragmentActivity` I get an error from

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container_sliding, fragment).commit();
```

saying that the method `replace` only accepts fragments and not fragmentactivities. Is there any other way to replace a fragment with a fragmentactivity as I would need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cant put fragment activity inside fragment.

Answer (score 0):

An Activity (and FragmentActivity) holds Fragments.
A Fragment can NOT hold an Activity (or FragmentActivity).

To solve your issues, either convert the FragmentActivity you wish to show, to a Fragment and simply replace the fragment, or you'll have to show an entirely new activity (by making an Intent and using startActivity(intent)).